# Macbook pro wont turn on?

Tags: macbook-pro

My mac wont turn on,

first the battery indicator only blinking, after SMC reset and unplug the battery than plug again, my laptop turn on, after turn on, i tried tu shutdown to put plat cover.

after that my mac wont turn on and when i try SMC charging only change to green and back to orange, but notting happen, unplug battery also not work, evrthing keyboard combination not work, i cannot turn on my mac,

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Many MacBook models will not power up if the battery is basically dead. And, reading between the lines I'm assuming this is an older model MacBook which probably still has its original battery - and therefore at much greater risk of having a dead battery.

You could try powering the MacBook up while connected to AC power and without the battery installed (this was possible with some models), but otherwise you'll need to replaced your battery (something I would recommend even if you could power it up without the battery).

**Further info**

Most MacBook batteries have a life expectancy at or around 1000 cycles.  It's not uncommon for batteries to exceed or fall short of this number; it's just an estimation of how long it can last.

Your options are to have the battery replaced or to only use it while connected to an AC power source (if this works for you). There are many 3rd party battery options available for purchase, so if you're still happy with your MacBook then that's your best option. If not, then it's time to upgrade.

If you do decide to replace the battery, then I would ensure that you purchase a battery from a reputable online store dealing with Apple products.

For example, the following are some well-regarded sites:

- [Mac Sales](https://eshop.macsales.com/search/battery)
- [Simply Mac](https://simplymac.sg/search?q=battery)
- [RAM City](https://www.ramcity.com.au/upgrade/accessories/laptop-batteries/131413)
- [Macfixit](https://www.macfixit.com.au/apple-laptop-batteries)

By buying from a reputable store you'll be sure to get a battery fit for purpose, regardless of manufacturer. Being reputable means they're only going to sell something that works and they'll stand behind the product they sell, regardless of the brand.

Comment: but battery still charged, because from orange led, its come to green, and battery indicator on side shown battery charged

Comment: To be honest, that's not at all clear from your question. Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367132/edit) your post to clarify that as well as provide additional details (your MacBook model) and explaining what happens if you try to power it up without the battery inserted. Also, can you go to Apple > About This Mac > Overview and click on the System Report button. Then, when the System Information window appears, select Power in the lefthand list and take a screenshot of the info on the right and include this in your edited question.

Comment: mac cannot turn on, how can i go to overciew? i changed with other battery still not turn on, this happen after about a year didnt use this macbook, and try to turn on after that i power off the mac, and cannot turn on anymore